# Trailing delimiter confuses pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, delimiter

A csv (comma delimited) file, where lines have an extra trailing delimiter, seems to confuse `pandas.read_csv`. (The data file is [1])

It treats the extra delimiter as if there's an extra column. So there's one more column than what headers require. Then `pandas.read_csv` takes the first column as row labels. The overall effect is that columns and headers are not aligned any more - the first column becomes row labels, the second column is named by first header, etc.

It is quite annoying. Any idea how to tell `pandas.read_csv` do the right thing? I couldn't find one.

Great book, BTW.

---

[1]: 2012 FEC Election Database from chapter 9 of the book *Python for Data Analysis*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a GitHub issue to have a look at handling this issue automatically:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2442

I think the FEC file format changed slightly causing this annoying issue-- if you use the one posted here http://github.com/pydata/pydata-book you hopefully won't have that problem.

Comment: Good to know there's a github repo for the book. Thanks, Wes.

Comment: I'd just second that this issue occurs in other locations; I just downloaded some weather data from the NOAA Climate site, and the end of each CSV file has an extra comma. I came up with the same workaround listed above. It's annoying, and took me a while to figure out why read_csv( ) wasn't working.

Answer (score 19):

For everyone who is still finding this. Wes wrote a [blogpost](https://web.archive.org/web/20230528053018/http://wesmckinney.com/blog/update-on-upcoming-pandas-v0-10-new-file-parser-other-performance-wins/) about this. The problem if there is one value too many in the row it is treated as the rows name.

This behaviour can be changed by setting `index_col=False` as an option to `read_csv`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's a very simple workaround. Add a dummy column to the header when reading csv file in:

```
cols = ...
cols.append('')
records = pandas.read_csv('filename.txt', skiprows=1, names=cols)
```

Then columns and header get aligned again.