# pandas misreads lines in file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read the following file with pandas using python 3.6:

```
$ cat tmp2.txt
somename     nan                                0       0     1     0     0       1       11    0.909091  0       0     1     0     0     7     1     1     0     0     0       0     2       
somename     nan                                0       0     1     0     0       1       36    0.972222  0       0     7     0     5     22    0     6     1     0     0       0     2       
somename UgzVrvH-ahjgfT9-NfN4AaABAg.8e3_FgQnopN8e4FLHwai7v0       0     1     0     0             0       25    0.920000  0       0     0     0     2     22    0     1     0     0     0       0           0   
somename     UgxyXxibolL_qOhMsyZ4AaABAg.8eApKy29u5J8eAxINbTH2m0       0     1     0     0       0       13    1.000000  0       0     0     0     1     10    0     2     0     0     0       0     0       
somename     nan                                0       0     0     0     0       2       56    0.839286  0       0     0     0     11    14    5     7     3     0     3       1     10
```

When I try reading it with pandas :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df  = pd.read_csv(header=None, filepath_or_buffer="tmp2.txt", delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
>>> df.values[2,:]
array(['UgzVrvH-ahjgfT9-NfN4AaABAg.8e3_FgQnopN8e4FLHwai7v0', 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 25, 0.92, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 22, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nan],
      dtype=object)
>>> df.values[3,:]
array(['UgxyXxibolL_qOhMsyZ4AaABAg.8eApKy29u5J8eAxINbTH2m0', 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 13, 1.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nan],
      dtype=object)
>>> df.values[4,:]
array([nan, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 56.0, 0.8392860000000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11,
       14, 5, 7, 3, 0, 3, 1, 10.0], dtype=object)
```

As can be seen when I print `df.values[2,:]` and `df.values[3,:]` I get an extraneous `nan` at the end.  It seems like this might be an issue with there being a maximum number of characters per line, but the man page for `pandas.read_csv` does not contain any mention of that.

QUESTION : What causes this and how can I get pandas.read_csv to correctly read this file?

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to this: [python pandas - trailing delimiter confuses read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719946/python-pandas-trailing-delimiter-confuses-read-csv)

Your input data has trailing delimiters on some or all of the lines.  Two easy fixes are to set `usecols` in `read_csv()`, or after reading do something like this:

```
if df[df.columns[-1]].isnull().all():
    df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```