# Python pandas reading csv parsing problem

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The dataset can be downloaded [here](https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/sltrends/data/330-071_meantrend.csv). Everything is good if I open the file with Excel or R, but when I load it using `pd.read_csv`, everything looks very weird. The `Month` column is merged to the `Year` column. Does anyone know what causes the problem?

The dataset looks like this:

```
Year, Month, Monthly_MSL, Linear_Trend, High_Conf., Low_Conf.
1944,1,6.985,6.968,6.982,6.954,
1944,2,7.025,6.968,6.982,6.954,
1944,3,7.054,6.968,6.982,6.954,
1944,4,6.980,6.968,6.982,6.955,
1944,5,6.967,6.968,6.982,6.955,
```

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("330-071_meantrend.csv")
# I also tried
pd.read_csv("330-071_meantrend.csv", sep="\s*,\s*")

# Results
    Year    Month   Monthly_MSL Linear_Trend    High_Conf.  Low_Conf.
1944    1   6.985   6.968   6.982   6.954   NaN
1944    2   7.025   6.968   6.982   6.954   NaN
1944    3   7.054   6.968   6.982   6.954   NaN
1944    4   6.980   6.968   6.982   6.955   NaN
1944    5   6.967   6.968   6.982   6.955   NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2006    7   7.074   7.079   7.092   7.066   NaN
2006    8   7.124   7.079   7.092   7.066   NaN
2006    9   7.110   7.079   7.093   7.066   NaN
2006    10  7.185   7.079   7.093   7.066   NaN
2006    11  7.086   7.080   7.093   7.066   NaN
```

None of the above works.

R works fine.

```r
library(reader)
read_csv("330-071_meantrend.csv")
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Trailing delimiter confuses pandas read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719946/trailing-delimiter-confuses-pandas-read-csv).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having seem to be due to the trailing comma (separator). You could construct the dataframe like this:

```
import requests
import pandas
import tempfile

with requests.Session() as session:
    (r := session.get('https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/sltrends/data/330-071_meantrend.csv', stream=True)).raise_for_status()
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+') as temp:
        for line in r.iter_lines():
            temp.write(line.decode().rstrip(',')+'\n')
        temp.seek(0)
        df = pandas.read_csv(temp)
        print(df)
```

Comment: You can just use `read_csv` with `index_col=False` as in the duplicate.

Comment: My Answer is specific to the question being asked. Please note also the word "could" in the preamble to the Answer.